# Boosting 5V 2A wall wart

Tags: current

Is there a way to alter the 5V 2A wall wart into 5V 5A? I want to power neopixel LEDs but I just need slightly more current supply.

Comment: Slightly? It's more than double. No, there is no way.

Comment: No. "slightly more" isn't 2.5 times more.

Comment: Please read Olin's subtle answer.

Answer (score 4):

Converting voltages and currents requires the total maximum power to not increase. In other words, input V * I >= output V * I (this is the concept of conservation of power). Therefore, it would be impossible to convert a 5V * 2A = 10W input to a 5V * 5A = 25W output because the 10W input is not greater than the 25W output.

Comment: I would say input V * I >= output V * I. Given that nothing is 100% efficient, maybe just input V * I > output V * I

Comment: yes, good point, updated answer

Comment: I guess the question is a bit different and can be rephrased as "is it possible to squeeze more power from a PS than it is rated for?"

Comment: The question is about altering a wall wart to produce more power, not how to convert its output.  However, your point is still valid and a good one, especially considering the OP might come back and ask about converting the output once he realizes that modifying the wall wart isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to alter the 5V 2A wall wart into 5V 5A?

No.  Not gonna happen.  Fahgeddaboudit.

> I just need slightly more current

A factor of 2.5 is a lot more than "slightly" higher.

If the 2 A wall wart could produce 5 A, then it would be sold as such and therefore fetch a higher price.  The manufacturer had to pick something as the spec, and they picked 2 A.

These things are manufactured in high volume, so saving parts cost probably got significant design attention.  Parts to support 5 A output would definitely cost more, and would take more space and weigh more too.  You can't just tweak a resistor somewhere and have the device output 2.5 times more power.

If you want 5 V at 5 A, go buy a 5 V 5 A wall wart or power supply.  These things are quite cheap nowadays.  You can buy a ready-made unit for less than you can buy the parts for separately in low volumes.

What you are asking to do just doesn't make sense.  Not even close.